# Selenium XPath: how to get href value of a use attribute

Tags: selenium, xpath, robotframework

I am trying to get the xpath of a svg that has an attribute `<use href= "#icon-map">`
So far the path `//*[local-name()='svg']/*[local-name()='use']` works, but it finds 84 entries.

How can I modify the xpath in order to select only the use that has the href as `"#icon-map"`?

Comment: Show us full HTML structure as code, Do not post the screenshot of it. Read [tour] and [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

`//*[local-name()='svg'][use[@href="#icon-map"]]`

or

`//*[local-name()='svg'][*[local-name()='use'][@href="#icon-map"]]`

See [example](http://xpather.com/RvdsayhS).

If you have more results than you expect then you should use more specific paths to the element or take your query into `(`..`)` and add number of an item into `[`..`]` like :

`(//*[local-name()='svg'][use[@href="#icon-map"]])[2]`

Answer (score 0):

If use is an `attribute` then you could do this :

```
//*[name()='svg']//*[@use and @href='#icon-map']
```

Also the above solution assumes that `#icon-map` is unique in `HTML DOM`

Comment: I tried your path and it did not work. I forgot to mention that the `<use href= "#icon-map">` is a direct child of the svg. The #icon-map is unique indeed.    
HTML:

`<svg _ngcontent-wkv-c84="" soho-icon="" icon="map" aria-hidden="true" focusable="false" role="presentation" class="icon"><use href="#icon-map"></use></svg>`

Comment: I have updated above, try and let me know if you run into any issues.